# Spark Scala : Connection to the Schema Registry

Tags: scala, apache-spark, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to get the list of all schemas from the Schema Registry with the following scala 2.12 code :

```
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val schemaRegUrl = "http://my_url:8001"
val registryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegUrl, 3)

registryClient.getAllSubjects.asScala.foreach(println)
```

And I am getting :

```
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:295)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:365)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getAllSubjects(RestService.java:863)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getAllSubjects(RestService.java:846)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getAllSubjects(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:508)
```

I am using :

- kafka-schema-serializer-6.2.0.jar

Can anyone knows how to resolve it? Thanks a lot

Comment: most probably schema registry requires authentication

Comment: Hello Alex Ott, there is no need to authenticate :(
Plus, when i do `telnet my_url 8001`, it throw me _Connect to my_url_

Comment: from error it looks like that it receives back the HTML instead of JSON

Comment: It is possible to force the output to be in json format ? Sorry if my question seems very basic, I am new at this :)

Comment: I resolve the issue by deleting the proxy config that I added in spark-shell. As you noted @AlexOtt, the output was in HTML format saying that the requested URL could not be retrieved. Thanks a lot, to put me in the right direction.
Cheers